# Getting error when trying to use Single line of text column in Calculated column

Tags: 2013, calculated-column, ootb

I have a 'single line of text column' and a calculated column. When I am adding reference of the 'single line of text' column to calculated column it gives me error of

> One or more column references are not allowed, because the columns are defined as a data type that is not supported in formulas. for test column

There are other 'single line of text' columns that I am able to use in my calculated column. This error is for only one column. Has the column got corrupted in any way? Also the internal name and display name of the column is different. Can that be source of problem?

**Update 1:** The formula that I am using is pretty simple `=[Approval Status]`. That's it. The column `[Approval Status]` is a 'single line of text' type column, though its internal name is different. Using this formula itself it shows error.

Comment: It would help if you show us the exact formula

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman: Added code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=[Approval Status]
```

Isn't that one of SharePoints workflow fields?

**I presume** you can't use it because the Workflow can set it at different stages and the Formula updating will either run before or after that update.

Comment: No, the field a custom field that I created.

Comment: If it got a different internal name then a field with that name (SPs workflow feld?) already exists.

Comment: I think that was the problem. The column `Approval Status` is already there (as you said for workflow fields), and when I put it in formula it tries to resolve to that column which, it seems, is not of appropriate data type. Rather than the column that I created. What I did was to update the column name back to its internal name, update the formula and then update the column name back. Then it worked!